# What value of thread_cache_size should I use?

Tags: mysql, .net, connections, tuning

I'm using Asp.Net together with MySQL. In the .Net connection string, I have set Max Pool Size to 150.

If I run the following I get these values:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections'; gives 66
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_created'; gives 66
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'connections'; gives 474
```

Which gives Threads_created / Connections = 0,1392.

So from that it seems like I need to increase [`thread_cache_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size).

But if I run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` I always see that I have a lot of connections open (most of them sleeping) because of the pool created by .Net. Do I still need to set the `thread_cache_size` as I still will reuse the connections from the connection pool? If the Pool Size is 150 do you think a good value would be to set `thread_cache_size` to 150+? Would this affect CPU and memory a lot?

Answer (score 44):

Based on the info in the MySQL Documentation you should do the following: Find out what the highest number of simultaneous connections mysqld has had using [**Connections**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections), [**Threads_created**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_created), and [**Max_used_connections**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Max_used_connections),

- `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Connections';`
- `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_created';`
- `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`

Try calculating the following

`Threads_created / Connections` : If this is over 0.01, then increase `thread_cache_size`. At the very least, `thread_cache_size` should be greater than `Max_used_connections`.

Comment: Thanks for great comment! I updated my question a little bit.

Comment: I think you were intending mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'connections'; (you have written max_used_connections twice)

Comment: I just want to add that by referring to this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size you should add 8 to Max_used_connections for the thread_cache_size value (without exceeding 100)

Comment: Actually, the manual suggests a default of (1% of the mac_used_connections) + 8 .... or 100...whichever is less.

Comment: For me the #'s are 264/103134 which works out to 0.0026 which is way less than 0.01   But my MaxUsedConnections is 72, so the last sentence is terribly conflicted

Comment: My max connections is 828 and created/connections = 9.15.  My question is, is it safe to set my thread_cache_size to 1000?  What are the implications of that?

Answer (score 13):

According to the MySQL docs, you should set `thread_cache_size` so that most new connections use threads from the cache rather than newly created threads. This saves some thread-creation overhead, though normally does not create a significant performance improvement:

> Requests for threads are satisfied by reusing threads taken from the
>   cache if possible, and only when the cache is empty is a new thread
>   created. This variable can be increased to improve performance if you
>   have a lot of new connections. *Normally, this does not provide a
>   notable performance improvement* if you have a good thread
>   implementation. However, if your server sees hundreds of connections
>   per second you should normally set thread_cache_size high enough so
>   that *most new connections use cached threads*. [(source)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size)

This would mean that you should set your `thread_cache_size` so that `Threads_created / Connections` (the % of connections that lead to the creation of new threads) is rather low. If you take the MySQL docs literally ("most"), the value should be < 50%. RolandoMySQLDBA's answer says < 1%. I don't know who's closer to the truth.

You should **not** set `thread_cache_size` higher than `Max_used_connections`. The final sentence in RolandoMySQLDBA's answer ("At the very least, thread_cache_size should be greater than Max_used_connections") doesn't seem sensible because it says that you should keep more threads in the cache than your server *ever* uses. MySQL will never put that many threads in the cache anyway -- it does not pre-emptively put threads in the cache -- it only puts them there *after* a client creates a thread and disconnects. If you never have X clients connecting at the same time, you will never have X threads in the cache:

> When a client disconnects, the client's threads are put in the cache
>   if there are fewer than thread_cache_size threads there. [(source)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size)

See also [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28701) by Michael:

> Setting thread_cache_size to a value larger than max_connections seems
>   like tremendously unhelpful advice... the cache can't possibly grow
>   larger than max_connections and even a cache anywhere close to that
>   size could only make sense if you have a tremendous amount of churn on
>   your threads... which, in a well-behaved application, won't be the
>   case.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28701

Comment: i think so! after i test this config,  "thread_cache_size should be greater than Max_used_connections" not helpfull.

Answer (score -2):

In the common working day, would a 'new hire' possibly need a connection?
Most magicians will not know how many people could be hired in the next few days.
V 8 of MySQL suggests CAP thread_cache_size at 100 to prevent overload regardless of max_used_connections.
For me, 100 is a good CAP.

See this link, please.

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_cache_size
```